# ASP.NET MVC 3 EF Code First - Problems with FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I am having trouble with SQL Server creating Foreign Key constraints when using Entity Framework Code First.

This is my scenario. I am building an application which allows us to log tickets against any of our systems and automatically assign the ticket to the relevant person.

We have Services, which can have many categories. The categories can have many subcategories. A help desk person can be assigned to Service, and Category or Subcategory.

Here are my classes:

Service.cs

```
public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public HelpDeskMember CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public HelpDeskMember DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HelpDeskMember> LinesOfSupport { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public HelpDeskMember CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public HelpDeskMember DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HelpDeskMember> LinesOfSupport { get; set; }
}
```

Subcategory.cs

```
public class Subcategory
{
    [Key]
    public int SubcategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public HelpDeskMember CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public HelpDeskMember DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HelpDeskMember> LinesOfSupport { get; set; }       
}
```

and finally HelpDeskMember.cs

```
public class HelpDeskMember
{
    public int HelpDeskMemberID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }

}
```

When the Database is being initialised, I am getting the following error message:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Subcategory_Service' on table 'Subcategories' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.**

I'm guessing the problem is with how I have defined the Key's and ForeignKey's. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs. You can in configuration for your entity use `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679204%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or globally removing `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.onetomanycascadedeleteconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Both can be set in [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) using `ModelBuilder` input parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do I set this configuration? Would it be in the DbContext?

Comment: @GarethLewis Exactly. I've updated also my answer with more details.